# Will Stack Exchange consider publishing a transparency (FISA, DMCA, etc.) report?

Tags: feature-request, privacy

GitHub regularly publishes its [yearly transparency report](https://github.com/blog/1987-github-s-2014-transparency-report) with the following data (or legally required mutilation thereof):

> - Disclosure Requests — requests to disclose user information, which include:
>
>   - Subpoenas, Court Orders, and Search Warrants
>   - National Security Orders
> - Takedown Requests — requests to remove or block user content, which include:
>
>   - Government Takedown Requests
>   - DMCA Takedown Notices

Google does the [same](https://encrypted.google.com/transparencyreport/).

Will Stack Exchange provide its users with some indicator of outside interference in its operation?

It would be great if the information were regularly published on the main Stack Exchange site, and not at [third-party servers](https://www.chillingeffects.org) which may come and go unexpectedly.

NOTE: This is not a duplicate of [Does Stack Exchange report on the numbers of requests and orders it receives from law enforcement agencies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199283) because other large Internet companies have since shown that transparency reports can be done in a meaningful way ([gag orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gag_order) aside).

Related:

- [Did the Stack Exchange staff members assist in the apprehension of Ross Ulbricht?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/did-the-stack-exchange-staff-members-assist-in-the-apprehension-of-ross-ulbricht)

Comment: DMCA [are already published](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177269/please-upload-dmca-takedowns-to-the-chilling-effects-clearinghouse).

Comment: @ShadowWizard - it's a third-party site and the information ain't consolidated. A top-level URL (https://stackexchange.com/transparencyreport) would be awesome.

Comment: It's not just Chilling Effects. He probably also wants a [warrant canary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_canary)

Comment: @Machavity - a warrant canary may not be cleared by SE's lawyers.

Comment: IIRC many disclosure requests are also in and of themselfes secret as in they can't tell people they happened.